# Replace # with / using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to replace the '#' in my url with a '/' (domain.com#home to domain.com/home)? And If so how would you do it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".con").load("views/startseite.html", function () {[...] });
   $("nav a").click(function (a) {
      a.preventDefault();
      a = $(this).attr("href").split("/").pop().split(".").shift();
      $(".con").hide().load("views/" + a + ".html", function () {
         $(".con").fadeIn("fast",
            function () {[...] });
      document.title = "Domain.com | " + (a.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1));
      location.hash = a;
      return !1
   })
   $(document).on('submit', 'form.ajax', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var that = $(this),
         url = that.attr('action'),
         type = that.attr('method'),
         data = {};
      that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
         var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
         data[name] = value
      });
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: type,
         data: data,
         success: function () {
            $(".flipbox").flippy({
               color_target: "",
               duration: "500",
               verso: "Anything!",
               onFinish: function () {
                  $("#no-color").css("background-color", "transparent");
               }
            });
         }
      });
   });
   $(document).on('submit', 'form.lebenslauf', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      $.ajax({
         url: './secure/secure.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
            code: $('input[name=bewerbung]').val()
         },
         success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.substr(0, 5) == "Error") {
               $('.error').html(resp);
            } else {
               $('.flipbox').flippy({
                  duration: "500",
                  verso: resp,
                  onFinish: function () {
                     $(".flipbox").css("background-color", "transparent");
                  }
               });
            }
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Example Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/views/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/views/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/views/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/views/contanct.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another question of mine is: What do I need to write when I want to use 'if(location.hash)' and where would you place it? To make it possible to use urls like domain.com/about without getting the home site.

Comment: the history api would be the way to do it, just keep in mind it isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: thats why i wanted to do it this way :-S

Comment: what do you mean *"this way"*? if you want to keep the back button working, you either must use a #, or the history api. (or iframes i guess). Your comment confuses me quite a bit.

Comment: The history api is the only way to replace the # with / in the address bar as Kevin B said. Browser support http://caniuse.com/history and a demo at http://html5demos.com/history/fourth

Comment: alright, i have to admit the #. can you please help me with me second questionn? :-)

Comment: your *"second question"* isn't very clear.

Comment: i dont know how to use the 'if(location.hash)' thing. for example when the client useses domain.com/about that the about.html loads in instead of the home.html like on domain.com

Comment: I dont see the point in posting all that code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we are on the same page, let me know if it works for you:

```
var path = window.location.href;
var newpath = path.replace(/[#]/g, "/");
window.location.href =newpath;
```

Comment: when i use this code, my site refreshs every seconds. where would you place it?

Comment: That is just for the one particular case when you want to swap "#" for "/" in your url, which would produce different location. If you do not have any "#" in your url it will return the same url, thus it will refresh constantly.